# Replace whitespace in JSON keys with regex

Tags: json, regex, regexp-replace

Hi I am trying to use regex to replace spaces in heys so a json like

```
{"december 25":"ho ho ho", "all I want": "christmas", "ids":["sandy","claws"]}
```

transforms to

```
{"december_25":"ho ho ho", "all_I_want": "christmas", "ids":["sandy","claws"]}
```

I looked into this: [Replace JSON key with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764576/replace-json-key-with-regex/39764831)

but I didn't find a way to tweak it to replace spaces instead of a character.

Thank you!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: It's a component inside an ETL tool, it uses JAVA underneath.

Comment: Why not using JSON parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex which targets space present only in keys,

```
\s(?=[^,"]*"\s*:)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pcIHd0/1)

Javascript demo,

```js
s = '{"december 25":"ho ho ho", "all I want": "christmas", "ids":["sandy","claws"]}';
console.log('Before:', s);
console.log('After:', s.replace(/\s(?=[^,"]*"\s*:)/g, '_'));
```

Comment: Just tryed it in a specific JSON and have this problem if, the json has an array it stops working (it selects keys and values), I edit my question to reflect this. Thank you!

Comment: @Alejandro: Ok let me change the approach and come up with something better.

Comment: @Alejandro: Changed the approach. Check now?