# Regex Remove Spaces in JSON String

Tags: json, regex

I have a wider automation which populates a lookup table and then serializes the data into a JSON file as this is my desired output.

I am required to remove the spaces once in the JSON format of the lookup column headers.

I am looking to see if it is possible to have a regex which will identify the headers and be able to remove the spaces.

JSON String below:

```
     [
  {
"INVOLVED PARTY ID":" 9445999606",
"CUSTOMER NUMBER":" 9445999606",
"PRODUCT":"Current Account",
"LAST UPDATED":"20/02/2020 10:33:00",
"APPLICATION STATUS":"Clearing Handbrake",
"PROGRESS":"Progress",
"APPLICANT":" ACCEPT FLEX INDICATOR Y",
"QUESTION 3 - HEART/CANCER CONDITIONS":null,
  }
    ]
```

Desired output after regex manipulation

```
     [
  {
"INVOLVEDPARTYID":" 9445999606",
"CUSTOMERNUMBER":" 9445999606",
"PRODUCT":"Current Account",
"LASTUPDATED":"20/02/2020 10:33:00",
"APPLICATIONSTATUS":"Clearing Handbrake",
"PROGRESS":"Progress",
"APPLICANT":" ACCEPT FLEX INDICATOR Y",
"QUESTION3-HEART/CANCERCONDITIONS":null,
 }
   ]
```

Notice only the spaces within the headers have been removed.

Any help on the regex string would be much appreciated or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Because the ammount of words in the keys or values could vary, it sem that regex should not be your choice. Regex is not made for counting. There are libs that could parse your json to object in the language of your choice and the you could iterate through it and remove spaces

Comment: If you are using a regex flavour that handles variable-width lookbehinds you could use `(?<=^[^"]+"[^"]+) ` (with a space at the end) which matches spaces which are preceded by a single double-quote. Note that this would fail for keys containing (escaped) double-quotes, and possibly in other edge-cases, which is why you should use a proper JSON parser.

Comment: I suppose you also want to remove the space inside `"APPLICATION STATUS"`.

Comment: @PierreFrançois re-edited question. But you are correct, space removed between application status.

Comment: In the same way, I suppose the space between `CANCER` and `CONDITIONS` also has to be removed.

Comment: From which language do you want to call a function to handle the REGEX?

Comment: @PierreFrançois Ideally C# as the wider automation is written in this language

Comment: See the solution of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59237326/replace-whitespace-in-json-keys-with-regex

Answer (score 1):

The logic here is to first creating a new empty result object, iterate over prev object keys, remove the whitespace from it, then assign it to result object as key and put the prev value (intact) as the this(filtered key)'s value;

```js
const yourData =[
  {
"INVOLVED PARTY ID":" 9445999606",
"CUSTOMER NUMBER":" 9445999606",
"PRODUCT":"Current Account",
"LAST UPDATED":"20/02/2020 10:33:00",
"APPLICATION STATUS":"Clearing Handbrake",
"PROGRESS":"Progress",
"APPLICANT":" ACCEPT FLEX INDICATOR Y",
"QUESTION 3 - HEART/CANCER CONDITIONS":null,
  }
];

let newData = yourData.map(obj=>{
  let regexedObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach( prevKey => {
    //pattern can be /\s/ too, depends on use-case
    const regexedKey = prevKey.replace(/ /g,'')
    regexedObj[regexedKey] = obj[prevKey]
  })
  return regexedObj
})

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this one works fine:

```
(?<=\"[A-Z0-9 /-]*) (?=[A-Z0-9 /-]*\":)
```

It has two non-capturing groups:

1. Catches alphabets (capital), digits, space, hyphen and slash followed by a double quotation mark.
2. Catches all the same char set before double quotation mark and a colon.

In between there is the space which gets captured.

Check this out https://regexr.com/4vogd